# Cassandra nodetool connection refused on Windows

Tags: cassandra, titan

I want to set Cassandra storage for my Titan DB.

For that I have followed instruction from 
http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/cassandra.html

I am using Cassandra 3.1.1, For Cassandra 2.2 or higher I need to explicitly enable thrift so that Titan can connect to the cluster.

So I run

> > /bin/nodetool enablethrift.

It gives me

> > nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused: connect'.

So I done below changes in /conf/cassandra-env.sh

> > set JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1/7199

still connection refused issue occurs.

Comment: Just a heads up. Titan comes with a prepackaged version of cassandra, which works out of the box with no concerns. If you are using a different version of cassandra (non-titan packaged). Some additional configuration is required. Most importantly though make sure you run the instance of cassandra that you intended to run. We were accidentally running two instances of cassandra which lead to a lot of problems.

Comment: Statement is not cleared I am following instruction as per titan

Comment: Do you have a standalone Cassandra 2.2 running? I believe what that note in the docs is intended for.

Comment: @Jason: No, but I have downloaded Cassandra 3.1.1

Answer (score 0):

In Cassandra 2.1 and earlier, the [compatible version](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/version-compat.html) for Titan 1.0, `start_rpc: true` is the default out of the box.

In Cassandra 2.2 and above, if you want to enable thrift, you either need to update `start_rpc: true` in the cassandra.yaml before you start Cassandra, or call `nodetool enablethrift` after Cassandra is started. The connection refused message on port 7199 (JMX port that `nodetool` communicates with) indicates that Cassandra isn't started.